# Dynamically creation of Json for antd Tree select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I have Json in the below form

```
[{
"shortName": "e2e",
"displayName": "E2E",
"description": "This is demo managed product",
"vertical": "Finance"   
},
{
    "shortName": "sfdsgs",
    "displayName": "fsaewgs",
    "description": "anything",
    "vertical": "Community"
},
{
    "shortName": "fga",
    "displayName": "xcdf",
    "description": "agfsf",
    "vertical": "Finance"
}]
```

I want to use this json to display the option items in an antd tree select based on Vertical.
[I want the filter to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RThQV.png) , The Antd tree select i am using is

```
 <TreeSelect
  placeholder="Filter here"
  dropdownStyle={{ maxHeight: 400, overflow: "auto" }}
  style={{ width: "100%" }}
  treeData={data}
  treeCheckable={true}
  onChange={onChange}
  treeIcon={true}
/>
```

I am using react hooks , could somebody help me to convert the above json to the format Tree select requires so the output could be as shown in the image.

Comment: you have to convert your array to TreeSelect accepted format which is mention in it's doc

Comment: I suggest you try to do it with classes first and then change it to functions to use hooks, cuz when u fill the structure asked in the documentation, it will be easier for you to migrate it. https://ant.design/components/tree-select/#header

Comment: i could frame the json and stored the dynamically generated json in a state variable and passed that state variable to TreeSelect but it is not displaying the child of that node i.e it is displaying the veritical and not the child of the vertical (fianance and community) , i am following the official documentation .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the demo on CodeSandBox 
first i created distinct data based on "vertical" values then with map function created children for selectTree data.
i hope this could help you :)

```
const ConvertToTreeNode = () => {
 const distinctData = [...new Set(OriginalJson.map(x => x.vertical))];
 return [{
  title: "Vertical",
  value: "0-0",
  key: "0-0",
  children: distinctData.map((x, index) => ({
   value: `0-0-${index}`,
   key: `0-0-${index}`,
   title: x
  }))
 };
}];
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-water-5yfwl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)